# php/xslt want a source document

Tags: php, xml, xslt, saxon, saxon-c

i getting this error by reloading the page in the error.log:

> Either a source document, an initial template or an initial function must be specified

Here my PHP Code:

```
<?php
// INITIALIZE PROCESSOR
$saxonProc = new Saxon\SaxonProcessor();
$xsltProc = $saxonProc->newXsltProcessor();

$lang = $_GET['lang'];
$rubrik = $_GET['rubrik'];
$seite = $_GET['seite'];

// LOAD XSLT SCRIPT
$xslFile = "../ressources/xslt/transform_article_partials_to_html.xslt";
$xsltProc->compileFromFile($xslFile); 

// SET PARAMS
$dir = __DIR__ . "/articles/" . $lang;
$filename = "{$rubrik}_{$seite}.html";
$filelist = scandir($dir, 1);


$xdmvalue = $saxonProc->createAtomicValue($filename);
$xsltProc->setParameter("articlePfad", $xdmvalue);

$xdmvalue = $saxonProc->createAtomicValue($lang);
$xsltProc->setParameter("lang", $xdmvalue);

// LOAD SOURCE XML
if($seite == null) {
  $filename = "{$rubrik}.html";
  if(in_array($filename, $filelist)) {
    $xmlFile = $dir . "/" . $filename;    
  } else {
    echo "404";
    exit;
  }
} else if(isset($seite) && isset($rubrik)){
  if(in_array($filename, $filelist)) {
    $xmlFile = $dir . "/" . $filename;
  } else {
    echo "404";
  }
}

$xsltProc->setSourceFromFile($xmlFile);

// RUN TRANSFORMATION    
$result = $xsltProc->transformToString();

echo $result;

// RELEASE RESOURCES
$xsltProc->clearParameters();
$xsltProc->clearProperties();

unset($xsltProc);
unset($saxonProc);   
?>
```

I dont know where is the error. I dont know if this error brokes some, because it works also with the error. On google i have found nothing to this error.

Comment: Any chance that happens when your nested `if/else` does not set the variable `$xmlFile` but instead does `echo "404";`? Perhaps you want `echo "404"; exit;` there, like in the previous `if/else`?

Comment: Likely it is the `compileFromFile` (expected a XSLT stylesheet) or `setSourceFromFile` (expecting an XML file). Check if paths are legitimate by printing out before calling and if they can be accessed by PHP page. Also apache error logs should have line numbers.

Comment: The exit was a write error, the error is now fixed, thank you!